# Dojo 1.5.0 Charting Legend missing

Tags: dojo, legend, dojox.charting

I just upgraded from Dojo 1.4.3 to 1.5.0 and noticed that my legend is now missing.
Anyone else have this problem??

I keep receiving the following error:

o is undefined in dojo.js line 73

This error occurs when

chart1.render();  //Graph shows but error causes the rest of the code in that javascript function to not execute (So, not legend because it's created after chart1.render(); line.

executes.  Works perfect in release 1.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the problem**..It seems like a bug but not 100% sure...Here is how to recreate it using
the Dojo Nightly Charting Tests code and dojo version 1.5.0 (Any web browser):

**NOTE**: This error occurs when adding a series to plot "other" and calling chart1.render(); more than once.  If chart1.render(); is only called once, no error and everything works as it should.  See addSeries for "Series B"...Remove plot: "other" from "Series B" and everything works OK even if chart1.render() is called twice.  This problem can also be recreated by just removing "markers: true" from the "default" addPlot and calling char1.render(); twice.

**Warning**: The HTML below in the code section isn't displaying 100% correctly but all the javascript code is present to recreate this problem easily.

**Eugene**: Thanks for the link to the testing page, that helped out.  Also, should I file a bug report on this??

```
    




Event 2D

 @import "dojo-release-1.5.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
 @import "dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit/tests/css/dijitTests.css";




.dojoxLegendNode {border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px; padding: 3px}
.dojoxLegendText {vertical-align: text-top; padding-right: 10px}




dojo.require("dojox.charting.Chart2D");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.themes.PlotKit.green");

dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.Highlight");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.Magnify");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.MoveSlice");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.Shake");
dojo.require("dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip");

dojo.require("dojox.charting.widget.Legend");

dojo.require("dojo.colors");
dojo.require("dojo.fx.easing");

var dc = dojox.charting;

var dur = 450;
var chart1;

makeObjects = function(){
 chart1 = new dc.Chart2D("test1");
 //chart1.setTheme(dc.themes.PlotKit.green);
 chart1.addPlot("default", {type: "Default", lines: true, markers: true, tension:2});
        chart1.addPlot("other",  {type: "Lines",
    hAxis: "other x",
    vAxis: "other y"
   });
 chart1.addPlot("grid",  {type: "Grid",
             hMajorLines: true,
           hMinorLines: false,
           vMajorLines: true,
           vMinorLines: false
   });
 chart1.addAxis("x", {min: 0, max: 6, majorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 3}, minorTick: {stroke: "gray", length: 3}});
 chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical: true, min: 0, max: 10, majorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 3}, minorTick: {stroke: "gray", length: 3}});
 chart1.addAxis("other x", {leftBottom: false, min: 0, max: 6, majorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 3}, minorTick: {stroke: "gray", length: 3}});
 chart1.addAxis("other y", {leftBottom: false, vertical: true, min: 0, max: 10, majorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 3}, minorTick: {stroke: "gray", length: 3}});
 chart1.addSeries("Series A", [{x: 0.5, y: 5}, {x: 1.5, y: 1.5}, {x: 2, y: 9}, {x: 5, y: 0.3}]);
 chart1.addSeries("Series B", [{x: 0.3, y: 8}, {x: 4, y: 6, tooltip: "Custom tooltip"}, {x: 5.5, y: 2}], {plot: "other"});
 var anim1a = new dc.action2d.Magnify(chart1, "default");
 var anim1b = new dc.action2d.Tooltip(chart1, "default");
 chart1.render();
 chart1.render();
 var legend1 = new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({chart: chart1, horizontal: false}, "legend1");

};

dojo.addOnLoad(makeObjects);




Event 2D
Go-->
Hover over markers, bars, columns, slices, and so on.
1: Markers, lines, 2D data, custom axis. Actions: Magnify, Tooltip.




That's all Folks!
```

Comment: I think you should. At least you can attach the full HTML file to the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Does charting tests work for you? Go to [Dojo Nightly Charting Tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/) and select a test, which uses Tooltips, e.g., [test_event2d.html](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/charting/tests/test_event2d.html). If it works for you, see what is different in your setup. If you found the difference, and it is related to Dojo, please [file a bug](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/). Don't forget to mention a browser you use, and attach a minimalistic test case as a file.

Comment: Yes, the test page works for me.  My code blows up on chart1.render(), not on the tooltip code.  I'll try to narrow it down to see what the difference is.  I'll report back soon.

Comment: See my post above for details on the problem.